# Ambiguous use of 'filter' when converting project to Swift 4

Tags: swift

I tried converting my project to Swift 4 this day.
I'm having an error on this line:

```
return Forum.threads?.filter({ //... })
```

The error says:

> Ambiguous use of 'filter'
>
> Found this candidate (Swift.Set)
>
> Found this candidate (Swift.Sequence)

`threads` object is implemented like this in `Forum`:

```
var threads: Set<Thread>?
```

So how to solve this..? Thanks for your help

EDIT : when revealing the error in log, here are the candidates:

```
Swift.Set:369:17: note: found this candidate
    public func filter(_ isIncluded: (Set.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Set<Element>
                ^
Swift.Sequence:35:17: note: found this candidate
    public func filter(_ isIncluded: (Self.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Element]
```

Comment: If you unwrap the optional do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes I tried it and keep getting this error

Comment: A simple `let threads: Set<Thread>? = Set() ; let filtered = threads?.filter { $0.isMainThread }` compiles in my Xcode 9, therefore a *self-contained* reproducible example would be helpful.

Comment: The question is about some Forum component with 'threads' not Threads, I've encountered something similar with Strings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To solve this, declare the type of the variable before you return it.

```
let x: [Character] = input.filter{/**/}
return x
```

This disambiguates the return type of the filter{} method.

Comment: Works great. Another way is `(input.filter{/**/} as [Character])` if you don't want a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a general issue here. For example this is an extension method on UITextView.

[image: ambiguous filter]

You can work round it by rewriting as a for loop. (Sorry, not great solution but will at least work.)