# Ambiguous use of 'filter' after migration to Swift 4.2

Tags: swift

am struggling to solve this small bug on the following extension on Dictionary. I realise there is a similar answer stating that declaring the variable type before returning it fixes it:
[Ambiguous use of 'filter' when converting project to Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339586/ambiguous-use-of-filter-when-converting-project-to-swift-4)

However I'm not sure of the 'filter' type? Any help would be great. Cheers

```
func pick(_ keys: [Key]) -> Dictionary {
    return filter { (key: Key, _) -> Bool in
        keys.contains(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine in Swift 5.1 though. Maybe just upgrade straight to that version?

Comment: Hmmm I can't migrate until all build errors are fixed.

Comment: Just comment that code out and replace with a dummy implementation like `return [:]`.

Comment: Ah would just love to fix it in 4.2 first, as have to stay in this version for now. It also says this under the error.

`2. Found this candidate (Swift.Dictionary<Key, Value>)`

Comment: And this candidate:

`func filter(_ test: (Key, Value) -> Bool) -> Dictionary {

        var result = Dictionary()

        for (key, value) in self {
            if test(key, value) {
                result[key] = value
            }
        }

        return result
    }`

Comment: Wait a minute, did you write the second one yourself?

Comment: Yep, it's in the same extension file.

Comment: @unicorn_surprise You really should have included your filter function in the question. It makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added your own `filter` method to `Dictionary`, this is not necessary, as Swift already has such a method: [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995335-filter).

This method seems to be added in Swift 4.2, which explains why you didn't get the error before. Since Swift has this method provided for you now, you can safely delete the `filter` that you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

For dictionaries, the parameter to the `filter` closure is a tuple containing the key and the value. It always used to be that you couldn't separate the constituent parts of a tuple in the closure declaration and you had to split it yourself in the body.

You can try this:

```
func pick(_ keys: [Key]) -> Dictionary 
{
    return filter { (pair) -> Bool in
        let (key, _) = pair
        return keys.contains(key)
    }
}
```

Or even

```
func pick(_ keys: [Key]) -> Dictionary 
{
    return filter{ keys.contains($0.0)}
}
```

And you should delete your implementation of `filter`, `Dictionary` [has one built in](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995335-filter) and that's likely the cause of the "ambiguous use" error.